# Intuition behind thinking of the transpose of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

Not directly related to the title, but I recently went through LADR, and did not find it particularly intuitive. I've started to work through LADW. I've found it much more intuitive.

There is one thing, however, that I don't quite understand. Why is it that we need to think about the the columns of $A^{T}$ when they are equivalent to the rows of $A$? What am I missing?

What are the motivations for thinking of the transpose of a matrix?

Comment: One comment is that the key property of the transpose of a real $m \times n$ matrix $A$ is that $\langle Ax, y \rangle = \langle x, A^T y \rangle$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n , y \in \mathbb R^m$.

Comment: If you want to take the dot products of vectors $b_1, \dots, b_n$ with all the vectors $a_1, \dots, a_m$, then the matrix product $B^TA$ has $b_i^T a_j$ as it's $i, j$ entry. This connection between transpose and inner products is extremely useful for concise notation, e.g. in linear programming or linear regression. Of course, in infinite dimensions, the transpose is a useful analytical tool, closely related to integration by parts.

Answer (score 5):

The transpose of a matrix is the matrix associated to the *dual* linear map. That is the main reason for the importance of the transpose in abstract linear algebra.

Let $f : V \to W$ be a linear map between two finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$ and $f^* : W^* \to V^*$ be the dual map. For bases $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ of $V$ and $W$, let $A$ be the $m \times n$ matrix describing $f$ as a matrix relative to those two bases. Then the matrix describing $f^*$ relative to the duals of those two bases is the transpose $A^\top$.

Working over the real numbers, there are a few different roles for the transpose of an $m \times n$ real matrix $A$.

1. As mentioned in a comment above, $A\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf w = \mathbf v \cdot A^\top\mathbf w$ for all $\mathbf v$ in $\mathbf R^n$ and $\mathbf w \in \mathbf R^m$. This is a crucial connection between transposes and dot products. (It is related to the abstract description above because the dot products on $\mathbf R^n$ and $\mathbf R^m$ allow you to think of the duals of these vector spaces as the original vector spaces in a "natural" way.)
2. The rotations of $\mathbf R^n$ around the origin should be $n \times n$ real matrices $A$ that preserve the dot product:
   $A\mathbf v \cdot A\mathbf v' = \mathbf v \cdot \mathbf v'$ for all $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf v'$ in $\mathbf R^n$. That's equivalent, by the previous property, to $\mathbf v \cdot A^\top A\mathbf v' = \mathbf v\cdot \mathbf v'$ for all $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf v'$, which is equivalent to $A^\top{A} = I_n$. This condition defines the *orthogonal group* ${\rm O}_n(\mathbf R)$. (Such $A$ have determinant $\pm 1$, and those with determinant $1$ are closer to actual rotations in $2$ or $3$ dimensions. They are called proper rotations and form the *special orthogonal group* ${\rm SO}_n(\mathbf R)$. Those with determinant $-1$ are called improper rotations and they are a product of a proper rotation and a reflection across a hyperplane through the origin.)
3. To compute the operator norm $||A||$ of an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ (this is the  least $b>0$ such that $||A\mathbf v|| \leq b||\mathbf v||$ for all $\mathbf v$ in $\mathbf R^n$), first you show for all real matrices $S$ that are *symmetric*, meaning $S = S^\top$, that $||S||$ is $\max |\lambda|$ where $\lambda$ runs over the eigenvalues of $S$, which are all real. Then for an $m\times n$ real matrix $A$, both $A^\top A$ and $AA^\top$ are symmetric (of sizes $n\times n$ and $m\times m$) and it turns out that $||A|| = \sqrt{||A^\top A||} = \sqrt{||AA^\top||}$. See Theorems 3.4(vi) and 4.1 and exercise 1 of section 3 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/matrixnorm.pdf).

Comment: While all these comments give food for thought, Treil's *Linear Algebra Done Wrong* introduces tranpose in the context of pivots, their relation to invertibility, and determinants as well. Dual maps and inner products are quite far from the point at which the transpose is introduced. Is there an immediate geometric interpretation of the transpose?

Comment: Treil's book really doesn't connect matrix transposes to dual spaces? Then it lives up to its title. :)  Anyway, I have added a few ways the transpose of real matrices has geometric meaning, especially that it lets you single out which $n \times n$ real matrices $A$ should be considered rotations around the origin of $n$-dimensional Euclidean space: those $A$ where $A^\top A = I_n$ (or equivalently, $AA^\top = I_n$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In regards to Treil, I'm sure he will once he reaches dual spaces, but he only get there in the second to last chapter of the book.